# NSFileManager application folders - ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I want to create 2 folders: "Images" and "Text", to download image type files to "Image" folder, and "text" type to "Text" folder.
Questions:
1)Where and how i should create them?
2)How to get path for this created folders?
Please write some short example, or give url to similar example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:  (your can learn more about NSFileManager from Apple's docs)

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];  //this get you to the root of your app's
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfoldername"];  

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])  //Optionally check if folder already hasn't existed.
{
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```